# Connection error between esri and Python

Tags: javascript, esri

I am trying a Python file to Javascript and I am using Esri library. I wrote the following code but it keeps giving me error.

```
var myObj //defined as a string which is passed to 
require(["esri/request"], function(esriRequest){
  var dd=esriRequest{
   content: {myObj},
   handleAs: "json",
   url: "www.example.com/pythonFile.py"
 }
}
```

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might miss passing the `token` in the content of `esriRequest` variable if `example.com` needs authentication. In that case, the correct answer would be:

```
token = "" //a string which gives you the permission to visit example.com you can take it after giving credentials to the mapserver or website
var myObj //defined as a string which is passed to 
require(["esri/request"], function(esriRequest){
  var dd=esriRequest{
   content: {"SP": myObj, token: token},
   handleAs: "json",
   url: "www.example.com/pythonFile.py"
 }
}
```